# Urban Airship + MeteorJS integration

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor, urbanairship.com

I have set-up Urban AirShip and tested it by sending a push notification using Airship's Engage dashboard to my Meteor Cordova application running on my IOS device. I do quite know how to send a push notification from my Meteor server using Urban Airship. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Meteor, but you can probably use the [Push API](http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/overview.html) to send notifications.